# Getting \n when trying to access .env variables using phpdotenv

Tags: php

I am trying to access .env variables in PHP but whenever I try to echo these variables I get a value of `\n`

This is an example of what I have in my .env:

```
PARTNER_NAME=testing
PARTNER_PASSWORD=testing123
```

To setup being able to access .env variables I ran this command:

`composer require vlucas/phpdotenv`

And in my php:

```
declare(strict_types=1);
require __DIR__."/vendor/autoload.php";
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv-> load();
...
$_POST["partnerName"]  = getenv('PARTNER_NAME');
$_POST["partnerPassword"]  = getenv('PARTNER_PASSWORD');
```

Comment: @TimLewis typo on my side, I am using `=` not `:`, will edit question

Comment: You get just a `\n` or you get `testing\n`

Comment: @RiggsFolly just `\n`

Answer (score 0):

If you were to read [the documentation](https://packagist.org/packages/vlucas/phpdotenv) _All of the defined variables are now available in the $_ENV and $*SERVER super-globals.*

```
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv-> load();

$_POST["partnerName"]  = $_ENV['PARTNER_NAME'];
$_POST["partnerPassword"]  = $_ENV['PARTNER_PASSWORD'];

print_r($_POST);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [partnerName] => testing
    [partnerPassword] => testing123
)
```

There then follows a section

> **Putenv and Getenv**
>
> Using getenv() and putenv() is strongly discouraged due to the fact that these functions are not thread safe, however it is still possible to instruct PHP dotenv to use these functions. Instead of calling Dotenv::createImmutable, one can call Dotenv::createUnsafeImmutable, which will add the PutenvAdapter behind the scenes. Your environment variables will now be available using the getenv method, as well as the super-globals:

And if you do that getenv() will work

```
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createUnsafeImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv-> load();

$_POST["partnerName_2"]  = getenv('PARTNER_NAME');
$_POST["partnerPassword_2"]  = getenv('PARTNER_PASSWORD');

print_r($_POST);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [partnerName_2] => testing
    [partnerPassword_2] => testing123
)
```